# How to resize and label Raid devices

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, devices, raid

I am asked to Create a RAID 0 array using the two spare drives on (5GB) on this Machine with the following specs

```
Size=2048MB
Label=RAID_0 
Mount it persistently by Label at /storage
```

Here is what I did.

```
$  mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
```

then

```
$ mkfs -t ext4 -L RAID_0 /dev/md0 

$ mount -t ext4 /dev/md0 /stroage
```

Is that correct ?

I am also not sure about how to make the Size=2048MB

Answer (score 1):

About your command:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
```

You create stripe raid array on two partitions sda1 and sda2. The size of raid array will be double of the smallest size of sda1 and sda2.

If you want to create stripe raid-0 array with 2Gb size you must use for it n-count disks or partitions with size 2Gb/n. In your example two partitions must have 1Gb size.

Don't use raid on one disk in real situations, it will degrade performance and data safety.

To mount file system by label use this command:

```
mount -t ext4 LABEL=RAID_0 /storage
```

For persistently mount:

```
echo "LABEL=RAID_0 /storage ext4 defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount -a
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the "Mount it persistently by Label at /storage" you will need to edit /etc/fstab and add a line.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have changed my answer.

Comment: Oh and just noticed a typo in the question and answer between storage and stroage

Comment: Oh, yes. Updated. But i see, @alkabary didn't need my answer.